# Get Process's cpu, thread, vsize, and rsize in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, shell, awk, grep, ps

I want to know the CPU,thread, VSize, Rsize of a process based on its PID.So i was using top -i 1 -l 1 command and grepping the corresponding values.But top differs form MAC 10.5 to 10.7 .Is there any specific way to get only those columns itself .

code
process=`top  -i 1 -l 1 | grep "$PID"
cpu=`echo "$process" | awk '{print $3}'`

similarly 5 10 11 for the corresponding(thread, VSize, Rsize) values in 10.5
But the columns differs in 10.7 .

Is there any generic way to get this in shell script
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this on solaris:

```
ps -eo pmem,pid,pcpu,rss,vsz,time,args | sort -k 1 -r|awk '$2~/<your pid>/'
```

Comment: Thank you ,This is really helpful .How can we get the threads ?

Comment: @user12345 `NUM=\`ps M <pid> | wc -l | xargs\` && expr $NUM - 1`